# How to use PowerShell/RegEx to find all HTML files with empty <title> tag?

Tags: regex, powershell

I am using Powershell to search thousands of HTML files for files that contain empty `<title>` tags. These tags may appear in the files with no space, whitespace, or line breaks in between the opening/closing tags. For example, they may look like any of the following

```html
<title></title>
```

```html
<title>  </title>
```

```html
<title>
</title>
```

So far I have the following code

```bsh
Get-ChildItem locationPath *.htm -Recurse |
    Select-String -pattern '<title>[\s]*</title>' |
    group path |
    select name
```

This works to provide me a list of all the files that match the first two examples. However, I am struggling to find a way to match the third example in which it has a line break and an unknown amount of whitespace. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select-String` processes the input line by line, so it won't catch your 3rd example. Try this to get the input as a single string:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.htm' -Recurse | Where-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) -match '<title>\s*</title>'
} | Select-Object -Expand FullName
```

Prior to PowerShell v3 you'll need to replace `Get-Content -Raw` with `Get-Content | Out-String`, because the parameter `-Raw` was introduced with v3.